# meta query for serialized value not working

Tags: wordpress

I have two metabox with checkbox in each one. It is named in the following code as `test2` and `test3`. I have saved both values in a single post meta key. On checking i found this is saved as the following.

```
a:4:{s:5:"test1";s:0:"";s:5:"test2";b:1;s:5:"test3";b:1;}
```

I want `test3` value to be used in meta query. I have the following query,

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'         => 'my_custom_cpt',
    'meta_query'        => array (
        array (
            'key'       => 'test3',
            'value'     => 1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I saved post meta in a key `my_test_pm`. I have tried giving this as key in `meta query` key. Still no posts is returned.

Comment: Did you try this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/meta-query-with-meta-values-as-serialize-arrays/62410

Comment: @Vel Yes. I have tried. Still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try like this?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_cpt',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'test3',
            'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', 1),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**or Use custom query**

```
global $wpdb; 

$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'my_custom_cpt')
AND `meta_key` = 'test3' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%s'",'%1%');

$ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_cpt' 
);

$posts = get_posts($args);


print_r($posts);
```

Comment: can you post your `test3` array value not serilize data?

Comment: `test3` is not an array. It's just true or false value.

Comment: `$settings['test3'] = $_POST['test3'] == 'on' ? true : false;`

Comment: This serialized value `a:4:{s:5:"test1";s:0:"";s:5:"test2";b:1;s:5:"test3";b:1;}` is saved in  key `my_test_pm`. I want `test3` key in this serialized one.

Comment: Ok. Give me few mins.

Comment: it is correct `update_post_meta(183,'test3', $settings['test3']);` ?

Comment: No. $settings contain `test1`, `test2` and `test3`. This settings is saved to a single key. So it's like `update_post_meta(183,'my_test_pm', $settings);`

Comment: you can use custom query?

Comment: If it's  the only way to use custom query, then i prefer changing the method of saving post meta as in the link you mentioned in comments

Comment: Yes. Please check my updated answer. only you can do this way.

Answer (score -2):

$args = array('post_type' => 'my_custom_cpt','meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'     => 'my_test_pm',
            'value'   => array ( 'test3'),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
         ),
        ),
     );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
Did you try like this?